# Textbox in Firefox cannot CTRL + V (Paste) after some updates

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, firefox

Before some Firefox update, my app is working fine but after that I cannot CTRL + V (doing Right Click -> Paste is still working fine) anymore. Any idea for this problem?

This is aspx code on the page:

```
<td width="50%">
     <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="RequestID" value="<% =RequestId %>" name="Request_ID"
            onload="document.LBS.Request_ID.focus()" onkeypress="if (fnCheckKeyPress(event) == false) {event.returnValue = false; return false;}" />
</td>
```

The problem is on the "onkeypress" field. If I delete that then it works just fine, but it cannot filter text (it suppose to have only digits) anymore. The function is called from the js file:

```
function fnCheckKeyPress(event) {
    // KeyCode Info: 13-ENTER ;  27-ESC ; 9-TAB ; 8-BACKSPACE ;  46-DELETE
    var nKeyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
    //alert(nKeyCode);
    if (nKeyCode == 13) return false;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        if (event.keyCode >= 3 && event.keyCode <= 39) return true;
        if (arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0].isChar == false && arguments[0].ctrlKey == true) return true;
    }
    if (nKeyCode < 46 || nKeyCode > 57) return false;
    return true;
```

}

Comment: Uhhh .. use `input` event instead of that awful mess ... and onload is not triggered by an input element, it fires only when external resources are loaded.

Comment: Sorry edited, the problem is on the "onkeypress" field.

Comment: No, the problem is the use of `keypress` event, which is not suitable for your purposes at all. As said before, use [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead.

Comment: Hi, this problem is not happen on Chrome or IE, just on Firefox.... and I'm not editing anything on this page since 3 years ago. That's why I think the problem may comes from Firefox updates.

Comment: It's time to edit it, see also [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and what else ... Your page is going to stop working in any browser on any upcoming update ... very soon, the warning has been there for a couple of years now.

Comment: More red on the docs: [charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode), [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) ... You see what I mean ..?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!